# HTC Wildfire S digitizer replacement

Tags: screen, touchscreen, htc-wildfire-s, calibration

I've just replaced the digitizer of my HTC Wildfire S because the old one was broken. The thing is that since the replacement, the new digitizer has become totally unresponsive. LCD is working fine though.

Just some small questions to rule things out;

1. Should I try to perform a calibration on the digitizer to make it work? I can't use the screen so I'm planning on making a Gold Card to perform calibration.

   (The new digitizer is totally unresponsive. Checked all connections, didn't clean them though but I guess this isn't causing the problem.)
2. Any other thoughts on what might be causing the problem? Could it be that the digitizer was already faulty at the beginning? Does this happen a lot? Bought one from Amazon.

Answer (score 4):

If its totally un responsive then you need verify once your harware whether its an exact replacement or not as HTC Wildfire S digitizer comes in two variants

1. With Chip
2. Without Chip

So match it with old damaged one and if they are same then the hardware will be faulty and you will need one more replacement.

Comment: Hi. I've checked the the old digitizer versus the new one and both didn't have an IC.

Answer (score 2):

Finally managed to fix this problem. Seems like performing the calibration with the use of a Goldcard solved it.

I'll leave the link to the instruction [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=21203638) for anyone who may have the same issue.

Please leave a message if you encounter any problems when going through the instructions provided in the link above.

Comment: The link may go dead, please collect the instructions and complement your answer with them!